# Saving data between postbacks

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a little issue here that i Can hope you guys can help with.

the problem is that I am have an auto-scroll function that scrolls the page between x intervals.

The thing is that there is also an auto refresh of the page(which is required due some data load) and the autoscroll stops because it's enabled by default.

I've tried to use the viewState but can't get it work.

Here is my ScrollFunction:

```
  function Scroll(enable) {
            if (Boolean(enable))
            {
                <%
        setAutoScroll("true");
                %>

            }
            else
            {
                <%
        setAutoScroll("false");
                %>
            }


            if (enable) {
                var delay = document.getElementById('<%=ScrollDelayValue.ClientID%>').value * 1000;

                var id = "";

                $('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, delay);

                //window.scrollBy(0, 50);
                $('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, delay);
                id = setTimeout('Scroll(true);', 5000);
            }
            else {
                    <%DeleteCookie("autoscroll");%>

                clearTimeout(id);
            }
        }
```

And on the Code-Behind i have this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ViewState["autoScrollEnabled"] != null)
        {
            scrollEnabled = ViewState["autoScrollEnabled"].ToString();
        }
        this.PreRender+=Default_PreRender;
    }

    private void Default_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewState.Clear();
        ViewState.Add("autoScrollEnabled", scrollEnabled);
    }
    public string autoScrollEnabled()
    {

        return ViewState["autoScrollEnabled"].ToString();


    }
    public void setAutoScroll(string value)
    {
        if (ViewState["autoScrollEnabled"] != null)
        {

            ViewState["autoScrollEnabled"] = value;

        }
    }
```

the setAutoScroll is called from the client-Side. On the client-side I have an event that runs a function on document.ready:

```
     <% if (autoScrollEnabled() == "true") { %>
            Scroll(true);

            <% }  %>
            <% if (autoScrollEnabled() == "false") { %>
            Scroll(false);
```

Please advise.. :)

Comment: How do you refresh the page for data loading? If it's not a post back the view state is gone.

Comment: Ahhhh.. I think that is the issue. I am using Telerik GridView and that is not making a post back when the data refreshes. I am totaly new to web programming.. Is there any other approach to get this working? maybe cookies?

Comment: If it is not making a post back when data refreshes, what else it is doing? I dont have much knowledge of telerik radgrid so I suggest that you use Fiddler or Browser's dev tab to check what's send to the browser when data is being refreshed. Btw.. what do you mean with "...and the autoscroll stops because it's enabled by default". The autoscroll stops because autoscroll is enabled by default? That doesnt make much sense to me :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If viewstate does not work, try to use Session instead.
Try to replace `ViewState["autoScrollEnabled"]` as `Session["autoScrollEnabled"]`